# Why is there a US idiom of using China to mean far away?

Tags: idioms, north-american-english

I live in the UK, and a lot of US culture reaches us in the form of film and TV.

There seems to be a trope of referring to something as being in China to mean it's a long way away. Things like:

- "I've done so much jogging I could have reached China by now."
- Super hero flies off and casually returns eating Chinese food.

In England this is usually Australia, being a large country at nearly the opposite end of the globe to us.

Using https://www.antipodesmap.com/, Here's what I'm seeing.

- Antipodean to London, the sea south of New Zealand.
- Antipodean to New York, the sea west of Australia.
- Antipodean to Los Angeles, the sea east of Madagascar.

So why does American culture choose China to be allegorically far away when you can get much further away on the globe? Wouldn't Madagascar be better?

Comment: Chinese food is *extremely* popular in the urban part of the US, so I'm not sure it's an allegory for something that is *not* a hearty bowl of noodles or wontons. If anything, it could mean that deep inside the superhero is a simple and relatable person with ordinary and inexpensive joys in life, just like the rest of us.

Comment: People in the UK are very aware of Australia and the fact that is more or less on the other side of the world, because history. I don't think anyone used a map to check whether it was the most distant country - it's just that it comes to mind very naturally when you think of somewhere far away. China is a place that comes up a lot in the US media and is a long way away geographically, so you can see how the same thing would happen. The cultural distance between the US and China may also contribute to the impression that it the quintessential far-off land.

Comment: I think it's simply historical. China has always been very far away, but a hundred years ago everyone had heard of it and knew it to be a faraway place. Unlike Madagascar, or, for that matter, Timbuctoo. I reckon one of the reasons Madagascar was chosen as the location of that children's film was simply because it is as far away from Hollywood as you can get.

Comment: I love that Antipodes site. As it happens the antipode of Beijing is in northern Argentina.

Comment: For a long time Australia was just a rumor to most people.  And China has been a "far away place" in European culture and lore since the days of the Silk Road.

Comment: I would have guessed that the "China" was used in England as "a far-away place" even before the US was a thing.

Comment: @CharlE - I hated Auntie Pode.  She was always soooo grouchy!

Comment: The point seems to be that ignoring their actual antipodes, the pop culture place you end up if you dig straight through the earth tends to be Australia (in Britain) and China (in the US) - consider these two clips from The Simpsons, a US TV show: http://www.tzr.io/yarn-clip/99054532-fc42-4401-962d-5c3756018829 (Homer drops a jar of pennies, which sink straight through the soil. Looking down the hole he calls "Hello? China?") and https://youtu.be/kP2GCfHkKmE?t=97 (Bart is digging a hole. Lisa tells him "If you keep digging like this you're gonna go straight through to China). No idea why.

Comment: Since when are expressions involving cultural or geographic references based on factual information? Plenty of them are contradictory, anyway. Half of Europe call a *roller coaster* a *Russian mountain* (*montagnes russes*, *montaña rusa*, etc.), yet the Russians call them *American mountains* (Американские горки). What is the *Irish goodbye* to Americans is called the *French leave* by the British, and somehow that is simultaneously cognate to *filer à l'anglaise* and *sich auf polnisch empfehlen*.

Comment: @choster I think there was a vote about the French Leave in 2016.

Comment: @choster And Danish pastry is called ‘Viennese bread’ in Denmark but a ‘Copenhagen bake’ in Vienna…

Comment: @Showsni similar idea but earlier: [*The China Syndrome*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_China_Syndrome)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Dig to China

As Americans have a general notion that China is on the other side of the world, the hyperbole *dig to China*, emerging in the late 19th c., seems an inevitability:

> When the shaft, which is 14x6½ feet, had reached a depth of one hundred and eleven feet below the surface, Mr. R.'s foreman and other experienced miners were of the opinion that further search would be fruitless; but Mr. Redhead was confident, and, to use his own expression, was 'bound to [*dig to China*](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=nyp.33433081921029;view=1up;seq=291), or find coal.' *Des Moines Leader*, 4 June 1873. Cited: *History of Polk Co., Iowa*, 1880.
>
> The citizens here use cistern water, but about one mile from the town is never failing water, which shows that we wouldn't have to go [*all the way to China*](https://texashistory.unt.edu/ark:/67531/metapth233452/m1/3/zoom/?q=%22all%20the%20way%20to%20China%22&resolution=4&lat=2229.133831774827&lon=3263.5439545102154) to get that precious necessity by means of wells, and lots of it at that. *Belton* (TX) *Journal*, 12 Jan. 1882.
>
> “This is my ground, every inch of it—sixty feet wide, one hundred feet long, four thousand miles thick. Yes, sir, every inch, if I choose to [*dig to China*](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?q1=%22dig%20to%20China%22;id=coo.31924063815181;view=1up;seq=116;start=1;sz=10;page=root;num=4;size=100;orient=0). …” — Edith Keeley Stokely, “Mr. Potter's Neighbors,” *The Ladies’ World* 17.6, June 1896.

[image]

Source: [*Harper’s Bazar* 35.5 (Sept. 1901), 482.](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=mdp.39015014835139;view=1up;seq=63;size=125)

Four months later, the text appears sans cartoon in a humor column in an Australian paper, where it makes even less geographic sense.

> Children:  We're goin' to dig to China. 
> Minister:  What for ? -
> Children: 'Cause you said on Sunday they were living in darkness, and we're going to let in some light. — *Northern Star* (Lismore NSW), 4 Jan. 1902.

#### Slow Boat to China

As an idiom, *slow boat to China* was apparently well-known [among those who gambled at cards](https://books.google.de/books?id=2i8LcBLqa9UC&pg=PA135&dq=%22slow+boat+to+china%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiwj9HhgfvhAhXmMewKHbOrDA04ChDoATAAegQIARAD) prior to the [1948 Frank Loesser song](https://books.google.de/books?id=NNJKAQAAIAAJ&q=%22slow+boat+to+china%22&dq=%22slow+boat+to+china%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjY6ebNgPvhAhXMDewKHY1FAOoQ6AEIJTAA) of that name, but appeared in print (*Washington Post*, 23 Dec. 1947, p. C8) only months before the song was copyrighted. The idea is that a steady loser of large amounts of cash would be the perfect gaming companion on a slow boat to China. To hear the song, you have your choice of [Ella Fitzgerald](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=ui_JwKRkxbY), [Bette Midler and Barry Manilow](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=mqfnT_gX8Sc), or this somewhat frightening [Swedish woman](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=gZfGmVgCwb0) channelling Billie Holiday. The song propelled the idiom into the broader language, even to the halls of government:

> The poor Hudson—[*the slow boat to China*](https://books.google.de/books?id=2i8LcBLqa9UC&pg=PA135&dq=%22slow+boat+to+china%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiwj9HhgfvhAhXmMewKHbOrDA04ChDoATAAegQIARAD)—was receiving her beating. — Jack Kerouac, *On the Road*,  1957.
>
> So they ﬁgured out at the White House the thing to do to get fast action was to get a bill through the Congress. Now if there is any slower [*slow-boat-to-China*](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=uc1.31158003863544;view=1up;seq=118) way of getting tariff relief for a speciﬁc product, than by trying to pass a bill through the Congress, I do not know what it could be. — Charles H. “Charlie” Brown (D-MO), Congressional Record, House, 22 Aug. 1957.
>
> I want to see newspapers from Halifax to Victoria by air—and not by [*slow boat to China*](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?q1=%22slow%20boat%22;id=ien.35556002530475;view=1up;seq=938;start=1;sz=10;page=search;num=932), because that is not good enough. I can remember how hard it was to get news about Canada when we were in New Zealand. — Canada, House of Commons Debate, 3 Feb. 1966.

Here, of course, it’s the time of the voyage in the foreground, not merely the distance.

#### Timbuktu

For many Europeans, the ancient city of Timbuktu in West Africa has been the very definition of an [exotic “middle of nowhere”](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timbuktu#In_popular_culture) ever since the hyperbolic images of wealth and culture in the 1550 [*Della Descrittione dell’Africa*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Description_of_Africa_(1550_book)) of Leo Africanus. As one blogger explains:

> When my grandfather wanted to signify something far out of reach or unimaginably far away, the thing or person would be “way out in [*Timbuktu*](https://blog.stevekemper.net/2012/05/03/golden-city-the-allure-of-timbuktu/)” or “gone to Timbuktu.” As a child I loved the word’s percussive sound and exotic aura. … It was years before I learned that Timbuktu existed outside his imagination. I also learned that for centuries of Western history, the imagination had been Timbuktu’s main location. — Steve Kemper, “In the Labyrinth,” 3 May 2012.

Yet for Alexander von Humboldt, China was at least one station on journeys to the far corners of the world:

> Was die Landreisen anbetrift, so sind dieselben in neuster Zeit nicht so ausgedehnt, als im Mittelalter: damals war es keine Seltenheit, dass ein Europäer die äusserste Gränze von China erreichte, dann nach Timbuktu gelangte, und endlich in Corduba ankam …
>
> *As for overland journeys, the most recent ones are not as extensive as they were in the Middle Ages: at that time it wasn’t a rare thing for a European to reach the furthest border of China, then* [Timbuktu](https://www.dwds.de/r?corpus=dta;q=Timbuktu), *finally to arrive in Córdoba*… — Alexander von Humboldt, *Lectures on Physical Geography*, University of Berlin, transcribed, Gustav Parthey, 1827/8.

In choosing a metaphor, the cultural distance is more important than the physical one. The longest non-stop flight today, for instance, is Singapore Airline’s [Dallas/Ft. Worth–Sydney route](https://www.cnbc.com/2018/05/30/singapore-airlines-to-launch-worlds-longest-flight--to-new-york.html) of 16–17 hrs., but Australia is simply not exotic enough for the metaphor.